# add data to html variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

html file

```
TEMPLATE2 = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <table width="auto">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"> <span style="font-size:20px; color:blue;font-weight:500">   Hdr1  </span><br /> </td>
            <td align="center"> <span style="font-size:20px; color:blue;font-weight:500">   Hdr2</span><br /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>1stRow:</td><td>{1strowVal}</td></tr>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <tr><td>25throw</td><td>{25throwVal}</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

By using above template, i have an other method with for loop, i tried many type of examples but didn't work. in my case i need to assign one variable at a time not by all at once.

tried below ways didn't work

try 1

```
TEMPLATE2.replace(NthrowVal, str(0))
```

try2

```
s = Template(TEMPLATE2).safe_substitute(NthrowVal="Alex")
```

try3

```
  msg = MIMEText(
       Environment().from_string(TEMPLATE2).render(
      NthrowVal="someval"
       ), "html"
    )
```

Any Suggestions

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace _string_ `"{NthrowVal}"` (e.g., `"{25throwVal}"`) with the Nth value? Where does the value come from? What is its data type?

Comment: I want to replace it with {NthrowVal} and Datatype is string #DHZ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python variable names cannot start with an integer so you will need to change 1strowVal to be something more like rowVal1. Next, use a format string to inject the variables into your string:

```
rowVal1 = "SOME_STRING_VALUE"
rowVal25 = "SOME_STRING_VALUE"

TEMPLATE2 = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <table width="auto">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"> <span style="font-size:20px; color:blue;font-weight:500">   Hdr1  </span><br /> </td>
            <td align="center"> <span style="font-size:20px; color:blue;font-weight:500">   Hdr2</span><br /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>1stRow:</td><td>%s</td></tr>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <tr><td>25throw</td><td>%s</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
""" % (rowVal1, rowVal25)
```

Comment: converted my other code logic, to load all values at once like you mentioned